# Rhino: Java numbers don't behave like Javascript numbers

Tags: java, javascript, rhino

I have an instance of this Java class accessible in my Javascript program

```
public class ContentProvider {
  public Object c(int n) {
    switch (n) {
      case 1: return 1.1;
      case 2: return 2.2;
      case 3: return 3.3;
      case 4: return "4";
      case 5: return new java.util.Date();
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

This is the code inside main():

```
ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
engine.put("ctx", new ContentProvider());

res = engine.eval("ctx.c(1)");

System.out.printf("rhino:> %s (%s)%n"
        , res
        , res != null ? res.getClass().getName() : null
);
```

The simple expression `ctx.c(1)` prints:

```
rhino:> 1.1 (java.lang.Double)
```

Now here is what happens with `ctx.c(1) + ctx.c(2)`:

```
rhino:> 1.12.2 (java.lang.String)
```

And finally `(ctx.c(1) + ctx.c(2)) * ctx.c(3)`:

```
rhino:> nan (java.lang.Double)
```

Rhino is performing string concatenation instead of number arithmetics! The following program works as expected instead:

```
engine.put("a", 1.1);
engine.put("b", 2.2);
engine.put("c", 3.3);
res = engine.eval("(a + b) * c");
```

Outputs:

```
rhino:> 10,89 (java.lang.Double)
```

Comment: Oh my god, someone actually used the "java" and "javascript" tags together *correctly*!

Comment: But why not just try `engine.eval("typeof ctx.c(1)")` and see what JavaScript thinks the type is?

Comment: typeof ctx.c(1) = object

Comment: @lunicon Nice solution! Please add it as an answer ([doesn't matter if you are the OP as well](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)) and accept it.

Comment: @lunicon you may want to take a look at my new answer because it's easier to code and to maintain

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a strange feature of Rhino: a Java `Number` set with `engine.put("one", new Double(1))` works as expected, while the result of a Java method depends on the return type declared by the method itself, which is read with the reflection API:

- if it's a primitive, like `double`, it's converted to a Javascript number
- otherwise it's handled like other host objects and the `+` means concatenation, either `Object` like in your sample as well as `Double`

You can configure this behavior with `wrapFactory.setJavaPrimitiveWrap(false)` on the `WrapFactory` in the current `Context`. This way the Rhino code can be kept in the bootstrap lines of your program and doesn't clutter `ContentProvider` (which I guess is some sort of configuration proxy)

From the [live Javadoc of `WrapFactory.isJavaPrimitiveWrap()`](https://github.com/mozilla/rhino/blob/1ac0c75539c71e0f794f68f7d1d70914b43a1550/src/org/mozilla/javascript/WrapFactory.java#L148)

> By default the method returns true to indicate that instances of
>   String, Number, Boolean and Character should be wrapped as any other
>   Java object and scripts can access any Java method available in these
>   objects

So you can set this flag to `false` to indicate that Java `Number`'s should be converted to Javascript numbers. It takes just two lines of code

```
Context ctx = Context.enter();
ctx.getWrapFactory().setJavaPrimitiveWrap(false);
```

Here is [the Gist](https://gist.github.com/RaffaeleSgarro/4cb135be73f3d3a0424e) with the full code I used to test

Comment: Thank you. It should be made bold in the documentation.

Comment: Agree. Instead I had to debug and download the sources. It also seems a weird default

Comment: I encountered this problem and searched all documentation but didn't find anything. Thank you saved my time.

Comment: Update: In Rhino java7 it works for every Number classes, bug In latest Rhino 1.7.11 no wrapping for BigDecimal and BigInteger!

Answer (score 1):

I created a value wrapper:

```
public static class JSValue extends sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.ScriptableObject
{
    Object value;

    public JSValue(Object value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getClassName() {
        return value != null? value.getClass().getName(): null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getDefaultValue(Class typeHint) {
        if (typeHint == null || Number.class.isAssignableFrom(typeHint)) {
            if (value instanceof Number)
                return ((Number) value).doubleValue();
        }

        return toString();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return value != null? value.toString(): null;
    }
}
```

and an edit function:

```
  public static class ContentProvider {
    public Object c(int n) {
    ... return new JSValue(1.1);
```

Now the expression works as expected. Thanks all.